# Opt file ownership and file permissions

Tags: linux, debian

I inadvertently upgraded my Debian machine to Debian 10 and it seems it broke a lot of things in the process.

The main being access to my `/opt` directory which is where I had installed most of my development SDK's (Java SDK, Android SDK, IntelliJ, NetBeans, Python) and after the upgrade, the file permissions of `/opt` had changed for me as a sudo user. Previously, as a sudo user I could access it without trouble.

So I am undecided, is it advisable to change its permissions? What is the best practice here?

Comment: As a sudo user, you should be able to access everything under /opt. What are the permissions of `/opt/*` that you cannot access them vis `sudo`?

Comment: Why are you sure this is a permissions problem? What are the exact error messages or other symptoms of a problem? Please, tell us the raw symptoms rather than your interpretations of them.

Comment: Previously, I could at least Read and Excute which I ould not after upgrade. I tried to Read but my linux responded by saying permission denied! I was shocked, i tried to navigate via terminal and tried to open by clicking but also said permission denied..I had to chmod 777 and my netbeans and java started to work, though netbeans keeps crashing, and am currently installing a new one.